# What's the proper NSDateFormatter format for this string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

February, 26 2010 21:34:00

Based on all the documentation I can find, MMMM, d yyyy H:m:s should be correct - but my NSDate dateFromString is returning null.

Comment: It works for me, would need to see code to say more.

Comment: That format string works fine. Check that your formatter and the date you're passing it aren't nil.

Comment: Turns out I was setting the locale within this method.

- (NSDate *)getDateFromString:(NSString *)dtStr
{
 NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM, dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
 NSDate *formatterDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:dtStr];
 [inputFormatter autorelease];
 return formatterDate;
}

Took it out and it works now.

Comment: Minor nitpick, but I've never seen "MMMM, dd yyyy...", only "MMMM dd, yyyy..." or "dd MMMM, yyyy" (note the positioning of the comma).

Comment: @Joshua - yeah, I know it's strange.  That's out of my control.  That's the format returned by the web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had lots of trouble with exactly this kind of problem until I explicitly set the formatter to en_US locale. systemLocale is NOT good because it may be something other than en_US, affecting e.g month/weekday names etc. This is a piece of working code:

```
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];    
[fmt setDateFormat:@"eee MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"];
[fmt setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
NSDate *formattedDate = [fmt dateFromString:someStringContainingDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

What region is the phone set to?  If it's not en_US, you'll have to set the date formatter to it using setLocale.

Comment: [inputFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]]; and I believe that is en_US